# Ghost requests in Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, application-server

We have Tomcat application server set up at port 8080 and Apache Http Server at port 80.
httpd redirects all traffic on port 80 to port 8080.

I am looking at the tomcat server console for our site and I see several requests on port 8009. These requests stay alive for as long as 100 to 150 seconds.

We aren't making any requests to that port. Where then are these requests coming from? Why don't they finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8009 is the port commonly used by [AJP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JServ_Protocol).

> The Apache JServ Protocol (AJP) is a binary protocol that can proxy
>   inbound requests from a web server through to an application server
>   that sits behind the web server.

[Here's more info](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/ajp.html) on AJP and its usage/configuration within Tomcat.

> The AJP Connector element represents a Connector component that
>   communicates with a web connector via the AJP protocol. This is used
>   for cases where you wish to invisibly integrate Tomcat 5 into an
>   existing (or new) Apache installation, and you want Apache to handle
>   the static content contained in the web application, and/or utilize
>   Apache's SSL processing.

Comment: Yeah but why are we getting any requests at that port at all?

Comment: I would check your Apache config. Perhaps use netstat to identify the endpoints of those connections